# Reset a simple counter

Tags: verilog, quartus, test-bench

I'm trying to write a simple counter using Verilog on Quartus Prime and a testbench in Verilog being tested with Questa FPGA modelSim.

The goal of my counter is to count up to 7 at positive edge of a clock cycle and wrap back to 0 after 7 or if the low assert reset signal is asserted.

I am getting the counting and the wrapping after 7 correct; however, the counter does not wrap back when the reset is asserted.

Module

```
// TFT_LCD_Driver Second Version
module TFT_LCD_Driver(  
    input clk,
    input rst_n,
    output reg [3:0] cnt    
);

initial cnt = 0;


always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
        if (!rst_n)
            cnt <= 0;
        if (cnt == 4'd7)
            cnt <= 0;
        else
            cnt <= cnt + 4'd1;
end
endmodule
```

TestBench

```
// TFT_LCD_Driver_tb
// spi driver test bench
`define clk_period 20

module TFT_LCD_Driver_tb();

    reg clk;
    reg rst_n;
    wire [3:0] cnt;
    
    TFT_LCD_Driver tft(
        .clk(clk),
        .rst_n(rst_n),
        .cnt(cnt)
    );
    
    
    initial begin
        clk = 1'b1;
        rst_n = 1'b1;
        
        #30 rst_n = 1'b0;
        #30 rst_n = 1'b1;
    end
    
    always #(`clk_period/2) clk = ~clk;
    
endmodule
```

Here is waveform of the incorrect counter

[image: reset signal is not wrapping the counter]

I expect to see that the counter goes to 0 when the low assert reset signal is pulled low. However, the waveform shows that it continues to count until 7 and then wraps back to 0. I have highlighted and marked the incorrect spot where I expect the restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 separate `if` statements in your `always` block.  The 2nd one takes precedence over the 1st.  Just before reset is asserted, `cnt` is 2.  The 1st assignment does not take effect, but the increment assignment does take effect, setting `cnt` to 3.

You should change:

```
    if (cnt == 4'd7)
```

to:

```
    else if (cnt == 4'd7)
```

---

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
        if (!rst_n) 
            cnt <= 0;
        else if (cnt == 4'd7)
            cnt <= 0;
        else
            cnt <= cnt + 4'd1;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Model a counter with asynchronous reset by adding an else to the post:

```
  always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
        if (!rst_n)
            cnt <= 0;
        else
          if (cnt == 4'd7)
            cnt <= 0;
          else
            cnt <= cnt + 4'd1;
  end
```